# Unable to ping from one container to another container connected in the same network

Tags: docker-entrypoint

I created two containers and connected them to a same network. But when I use the commands:

```
docker exec -ti docker-client1 sh 
ping -c 2 docker-client2
```

I get the error:

> "sh: 1: ping: not found"

I have used the container names instead of IP address, as both are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ping` program is not available in your image. Check what OS your image is based on, then research how to install packages on that OS and what package the `ping` program is contained in.

Comment: Thankx, i am running on Raspberry pi. so its Raspbian Jessie OS.